# Returning back to an HTML page

Tags: html, c, cgi

I have two html files called `home.html` and `options.html`. In the `options.html`, after I clicked the submit button, I am now in the `cgi-bin` directory of my webserver. What should be the format of my `anchor` tag so I can go back to the `home.html` page?

This is the code:

```
<a href='localhost/cgi-bin'>GO BACK</a>
```

The error I encounter is:

```
The requested URL /cgi-bin/localhost/home.html was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to be:

`<a href="http://localhost/home.html">GO BACK</a>`

Comment: Using an absolute path will make your site working only locally, this will never work once published on a different server.

Comment: @RenkyaZ this is just a project. This doesn't involve publishing on a different server. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I have understood your issue, but this probably could work:

```
<a href='/home.html'>GO BACK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
<a href='javascript:history.back(-1)'>GO BACK</a>
```

Comment: I am not using Javascript. This is just CGI,C and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use

`<a href='localhost/cgi-bin/home.html'>GO BACK</a>`

Comment: Still not found. The `home.html` is on the `/var/www` directory while the CGI script is on `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`.

Answer (score 0):

if both pages are in same directory you can do something like this

```
<a href="home.html">GO BACK</a>
```

else give absolute path

```
<a href="http://webserver/cgi-bin/home.html" >GO BACK</a>
```

post complete directory structure of both files so that we can find a relative path.